# Maven update issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

while updating maven I am getting an error as An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
'org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.IJobManager org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getJobManager()'

How I can resolve this issue?
I tried changing the workspace.
mvn eclipse: clean

Both of the above approaches didn't work!
can anyone help me to resolve this?

eclipse version :2020-12 (4.18.0)

Comment: First do not use `eclipse:..` anymore is long retired. Import your project via Eclipse itself. Apart from that which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail. But Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) is 11 years and 18 releases old, so very few people will remember anything about it.